# In opencv how to delete an element of vec2f

Tags: opencv

I want to delete the element of

```
  vector<Vec2f> lines;
```

to add a new element i know I have to do

```
lines.push_back(a,b);
```

similarly how do i remove a element from it.

I tried :

```
lines.pop_back(a,b);
lines.remove(a,b);
lines.delete(a,b);
```

please tell me how I should remove an array element.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines.push_back(a,b);
```

is wrong. You need to `push_back()` a `Vec2f`, e.g.

```
// initialize Vec2f 'v' with values a, b
cv::Vec2f v(a, b);
// add to container
lines.push_back(v);
```

Then you would be able to use:

```
lines.pop_back();
```

which removes the `Vec2f` at the end of `lines`, or:

```
lines.erase(lines.front() + i);
```

where `i` is the index of the element you wish to remove, which in turn removes an element at a position of your choosing.

To explain further, the `vector` is just being used as a container of `Vec2f`, i.e. it doesn't actually know how to deal with `Vec2f` data specifically. Rather, it is specified to deal with abstracted [template classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29).